# Why can I not get a compile-time error referencing a non-existent key in a Dart map?

Tags: flutter, dart, compile-time

I am new to Dart and was expecting to get a compile-time error for the following code:

```
  final Map screens = const {
    "START": 'start_screen',
    "QUESTIONS": 'questions_screen',
    "RESULTS": 'result_screen',
  };

...
  activeScreen = screens['QUESTIONS1']!;
```

I know that I can use *containsKey* to find it a real time, but if my map is *const*, why cannot the Dart compiler find this code error?

Comment: The Dart language has no way of conveying that a function/method (in this case, `Map.operator []`) can be evaluated at compile-time.  The compiler treats `Map` like any other class; it has no special semantic understanding of `Map` objects and their methods.  Could the Dart compiler have special cases for `const` `Map` objects?  Sure.  Does it?  No.  Would such special cases offer sufficient benefit to add?  That's debatable.